# LightSwitch HTML change format format with Button_execute event

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-lightswitch

Is there a way to format a button such as change the text or background color when it it pressed to make it a sort of toggle switch?

To make this more complicated I'm talking about a button that I add to a table (on every row of the table) and I only want to change the format of the button that's clicked not all buttons in the table.  changing the format of the selected row would be an option too if that's possible.

If this were a _postRender I could use element and contentItem but how can I use those from with the ButtonClick_execute?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery css method. 
***You Must Have The Jquery Library Linked in your html***

```
$('#ID_Of_BUTTON').click(function(){ //This code will be executed when button is clicked
$('#ID_OF_BUTTON').css('Css Attribute','value'); //Put css Attribute as color
$("#ID_OF_BUTTON").attr('value', 'NAME HERE'); //This Changes the Name or Value
});`
```

***You Could Also Make two different styles in your css, and just toggle the classes.***

```
$('#ID_OF_Button').click(function(){
$('#ID_OF_Button').toggleClass('Clicked');
$('#ID_OF_BUTTON').toggle(
function(){
    $(this).val('on'); //Changes Value to on
}, 
function(){
    $(this).val('off'); //Changes Value to off
}
);
});
```

Css:    .clicked {color: green;}

Comment: How do I get the '#ID_OF_BUTTON' when I put a single button control in the table and it creates a button on each row?  I can't possibly copy this code for every button there could be ~500k buttons (rows).  I need the code to work with the selected row somehow.